# How can I set mouse scroll up, page go up, while the opposite like trackpad?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, macos

I just come from windows to mac, so I have some habits in windows that I want to continue on my mac. In windows, I use trackpad for natural way, which means when I move upwards on trackpad, the page goes down. While when I use mouse, I set the mouse as traditional way, which means I scroll down, the page goes down.

Now, when I come to mac, the issue comes. I mac, I know there is setting about natural way or not for both mouse and trackpad, however, they cannot be changed simultaneously. If I set trackpad as the natural way, the mouse goes to natural way automatically. What I NEED is the natural way for my trackpad, and un-natural(tranditional) way for my mouse.

How can I achieve above? I really want to keey my habits in windows.

Comment: Check out karabiner elements.  Probably will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I downloaded this app, but how can I map mouse scroll up to scroll down?

Comment: I haven't looked into this issue, but what William says may or may not be true. Karabiner was rebuilt due to some changes in Sierra. It has beefed up a bit, but it still doesn't have all the functionality that the old version 10 had. With that version you definitely can do that. Karabiner Elements might not be capable though. — I'll take a look at this later.

Comment: In System Preferences you got separate settings for Mouse and Trackpad. I'm not on my macbook right now and I can't check or remember, but I'm pretty sure both of them should have a separate checkbox for "Scroll direction natural".

Comment: Yes, there are separated settings, but they cannot be set differently at the same time.

Comment: I hoped that wouldn't be the case, though similar questions made me think it might be... I'm seeing people saying [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/) doesn't work, but have you tried it? If it doesn't... This might be a last resort type of thing, but [Steermouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) can change the scroll direction of a specific mouse. It is fairly expensive if this is the only thing you need it for, but I don't know any other apps that could do this a bit cheaper.

Comment: I have tried scroll reverser, it works!!! Appreciate your advice!!!  Now I can keep my windows habit now, LOL